# can make the ResponsiveImageGallery as auto and manual?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I using the responsive image gallery. I want the slide show as auto and manual. Is there any option to change this? Any one can help? please! The demo link is
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more Informationen and Code could help. But I think i have the answer you are lookng for, if you check the Homepage: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/
in the Feedback-Section, there is a post from James made on MAY 23, 2012 AT 18:41
explaining Auto-Slideshow.

Quote:

> ...
>
> In the file gallery.js, in the function _initCarousel add these lines after
> $esCarousel.elastislide( ‘setCurrent’, current ); (~ line 103) :

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   _navigate( ‘right’ );
 }, 5000);
```

> You just have to change 5000 to the value you want.

I hope this covers your question.

Comment: thank you! Its worked for me. And i want one more thing, i want to change the value of imageW . I want to give this as image width. In the thumbnail, i having the different width images.

Comment: yes I accepted. but i want to change the value of imageW as image width in gallery.js

Comment: Line 84: in the Jquery.elastislide.js _imageW: 190_ just comment it out. than the thumbnails are in the right Size. I hope this is what you wanted. :)

Comment: Upss... My mistake, you have to comment out **also** the line _imageW  : 65, _ in the file gallery.js . Please write aline back if it worked as you wanted it. Thx

Comment: width is fitted but the carousal is not working. the thumbnail is not moving